# Django - Can't import ListView and DetailView classes

Tags: django, listview, import

I'm going through Django tutorial (part 4 - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/) and need to import this:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
```

I copypasted code snippet with this import line, but PyDev underscored `DetailView` and `ListView` as unresolved import.
I opened module `django.views.generic` and saw that the only thing it contain is:

```
class GenericViewError(Exception):
    """A problem in a generic view."""
    pass
```

Neither DetailView, nor ListView, nor something other at all.

What's wrong? (I use django ver. 1.2.5)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer - tutorial I use is for the development version (latest for this moment - 1.3).

For the strange reasons I ignored the notice on each tutorial page:

"This document is for Django's development version, which can be significantly different from previous releases. Get older docs here: 1.2, 1.1, 1.0"

Comment: Yup, you were using the new 1.3 class-based generic views